# No actualización de la página de una aplicación web

Tags: php

Estoy creando una aplicación web en PHP. Almaceno información en una tabla la cual es volátil ya que hasta que no se pincha en el botón de finalizar no se añade a la base de datos. El problema lo tengo cuando borro algún elemento de la tabla debido a que se me actualiza la página. He probado a guardar la información en una variable y una vez que se recargue la página volver añadirla a la tabla pero no funciona. ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Hola @adamista, bienvenido/a a SO en español, podrías agregar lo que has intentado hasta ahora? como por ejemplo que parte del código crees que no funciona. Cual quier duda sobre como preguntar [chequea esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6):

Las variables se inicializan cada vez que recarga la página, así que no servirán de mucho en este caso. Necesitas algún método que con el que los datos se mantengan y persistan incluso después de recargar la página.

Para ello tienes varias opciones, la que más convenga dependerá del caso en particular y de las restricciones que presente: ¿Son muchos datos? ¿Quieres que se mantenga de una sesión a la siguiente? ¿Cómo de seguro debe ser? ¿Quieres hacerlo en el lado del cliente o del servidor? ¿Cómo estás implementando el borrado y la tabla? etc.

Algunas de las opciones disponibles:

**IndexedDB**

Asumiendo que la tabla en la que el usuario introduce datos es en el lado del cliente y en HTML, podrías implementar esta base de datos orientada a objetos introducida en HTML5, usando una clave para guardar/acceder los datos.

Pros:

- Puedes guardar muchos datos.
- Muy eficiente y buen rendimiento.

Contras:

- Su soporte es bastante limitado.
- Implementación algo complicada.

**Cookies**

Un clásico. Sólo tendrías que guardar los datos en la cookie que se puede desarrollar en casi cualquier lenguaje.

Pros:

- Fáciles de implementar.
- Podrías implementarlas en PHP o JavaScript

Contras:

- La cantidad de datos que puedes guardar es limitada.
- Pueden no ser tan seguras como otros métodos.

**LocalStorage / SessionStorage**

Otra solución en el lado del cliente. También introducidos en HTML5, LocalStorage y SessionStorage te permiten mantener información de manera persistente (SessionStorage exclusivamente hasta el final de la sesión). En tu caso en particular, parece que SessionStorage sería una mejor opción porque no importarían los valores de la tabla de una sesión a la siguiente.

Pros:

- Fáciles de implementar.
- Permiten más datos que las cookies y se almacenan de manera local (no viajan al servidor)

Contras:

- Si las cookies están deshabilitadas, también se deshabilitará esta opción.
- En páginas seguras (https) los valores se guardan de manera "independiente" y si accedes al página sin el https puede que no los veas, lo que puede crear cierta confusión.

---

Y el procedimiento sería sencillo:

- Utiliza uno de estos métodos para guardar los datos cada vez que un usuario borra un dato (antes de que se recargue la página; p.e.: en el evento `onbeforeunload`)
- Cuando la página se cargue de nuevo:

  - Comprueba si existen datos guardados
  - Añádelos a la tabla.

Alternativamente, podrías buscar un método para borrar datos de la tabla sin necesidad de recargar la página completa (con JavaScript y/o AJAX). Eso haría las cosas más sencillas porque así no tendrías que preocuparte por mantener los datos si realmente no lo necesitas.

Comment: Puedes encontrar el soporte de indexDB, localStorage y otros elementos de HTML5 para los navegadores en el siguiente sitio: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Voy a intentar realizarlo con localstorage ya que la seguridad no es lo más importante en mi aplicación web

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a borrar de la tabla de alguna otra forma. Como no has puesto código no puedo decirte como hacerlo concretamente, pero supongo que podrías borrar los elementos con una petición ajax o algo así para evitar que recargue la página.

Comment: Si tienes dudas con respecto a lo que ha hecho deberías pensar en preguntar con un comentario(como este). Preguntar por código, por ejemplo, si no lo han solicitado aún.